# Kak Etot Kod napisat Cherez Refleciyu

Tags: c#

```
 protected override Student ToModel(XmlNode xnode)
        {
            Student item = new Student();
            foreach (XmlNode xchild in xnode.ChildNodes)
            {
                switch (xchild.Name)
                {
                    case Keywords.FirstName:
                        item.FirstName = xchild.InnerText;
                        break;

                    case Keywords.LastName:
                        item.Lastname = xchild.InnerText;
                        break;

                    case Keywords.BirthDate:
                        if (DateTime.TryParse(xchild.InnerText, out DateTime date))
                        {
                            item.BirthDay = DateTime.Parse(xchild.InnerText);
                        }
                        break;

> `Цитата`

                }
            }
            return item;`введите сюда код`
```